# Support for exception handling is disabled

Tags: c++, c, exception, kernel, driver

Title is basically my problem. I tried enabling exception handling but I cannot seem to find what is command that I should write in command line\additional options in C/C++ properties.

I also want to mention I am developing a kernel driver so maybe thats why -fexceptions and such things I've tried didn't work

Comment: Since kernel drivers must be written in c, you cannot enable exceptions there at all. c doesn't have any exception handling facilities.

Comment: Pick a single language, C or C++ as there is no C/C++ language.  They are distinct languages.  For example, C++ has `try`, `catch` and `throw` for exceptions.  In C language, you have to write your own exception throwing and catching mechanisms.